# change all ids in $.html() (or better ie7 clone alternative)

Tags: jquery, html, string, internet-explorer-7, clone

After much banging my head against the wall, I found this: http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/9777  Yay!

My problem is that when I `$.clone()` an element in ie7 and try to change all `id`s with `$myClonedElement.find("*[id]").andSelf().each(function() { $(this).attr("id", $(this).attr("id") + "-" + idNumberVariableForDynamicDatabasePagination); });`, the `id`s for the clone also change.

I'm guessing I should use `$.html()` instead (if you have a better alternative, please suggest it), and append `'-' + idNumberVariableForDynamicDatabasePagination` to each `id`.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Avoid the bug by not using `.attr`, according to the bug report you linked to.

```
this.id = this.id + "-" + somenumber
```

I don't have a real version of IE7 to test this with.

Comment: Ty!  Well, it stopped changing the `id` of the original, but now it doesn't alter any `id`s whatsoever lol.  Is `this` getting lost in the `find` or something?

Comment: It shouldn't be, `$(this).attr("id","someid")` is the same as `this.id = someid`. If the former works in all other browsers, so should the latter.

Comment: `attr` changes the `clone` and the original while `this.id` doesn't change anything, and `prop` acts just like `this.id`.  This is ie7 only

Comment: Do both methods work in the other browsers? (just confirming)